# VSCODE not recognizing .env* files for markup porpuses and not recognizing .env.local.* files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

Environment:

NextJs, React, VsCode

1. Syntax highlights not being recognized by VSCODE.

I have installed the following extensions:

- [ENV](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IronGeek.vscode-env)
- [DotEnv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikestead.dotenv)

Have done the followin on my `json` config file:

```
"files.associations": {
            "*.js": "javascriptreact",
            "*.env.development": "env",
            "*.env.production": "env",
            "*.env.local": "env",
    },
```

2. VsCode should recognize .env naming as per the file I have created:

`.env.local.example`

I have tested a public variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_LOCAL_VARIABLE = "Some public stuff"` and it does not work when I test it on the browser. When I add the termination `.example` to `.env.local` file, Vscode stops recognizing the file at all.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you used the `create-react-app` to setup your project?

Comment: @NemanjaLazarevic I have used ```create-next-app```

Comment: Does `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_LOCAL_VARIABLE ` enables you to print out the variable in your browser?

Comment: @NemanjaLazarevic if I remove the file termination ```.example```, keeping the file naming = ```.env.local``` it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 8):

Your configs glob patterns seem to be the problem.

`*.env.local` covers `example.env.local` and not `.env.local.example`. If you append identifiers to the end of the filename your config should be like this:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact",
    ".env.development*": "env",
    ".env.production*": "env",
    ".env.local*": "env",
},
```

Or even this would be sufficient I think:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact",
    ".env.*": "env",
},
```

UPDATE:

Also it depends on the plugins you have installed. `env` type is registered by an `ENV` plugin, if you don't have it installed you can use builtin `properties` type.

```json
"files.associations": {
    ".env.*": "properties",
},
```

Comment: Why haven't I've done that before 

Comment: @n1kk I tried this on my vscode config, but the icon in .env.local is still different from .env. Can you tell me what to check? I agree your answer is correct, but I don't know the reason... so if you have another option can you share about this?

Comment: Hey @horoyoio, what version did you try, long or short? I think the long version has a mistake, I guess I didn't pay enough attention but the seems like the last dot before the asterisk should be removed.

Comment: @horoyoio I've tested it out on a clean VSCode, it doesn't have `env` as a type, but you can use `".env.*": "properties"` it'll give same syntax highlight. Or install `ENV` extension.

Comment: @n1kk First of all, thank you so much for replying quickly. In my case, it was solved by installing an extension called vscode-icons, not the "ENV" plugin. I didn't want to set rules for my files with ".properties". After installing vscode-icons ' ".env.*": "env",' this works fine. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

`create-next-app` supports only the following variable names:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

You overriding VSCode highlight config will not make a difference how your project exposes environment variables to the browser.
You will need to override the `create-next-app` configuration or use the supported naming convention.

Comment: Take a look at this naming example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/environment-variables/.env.local.example

Comment: How did they manage to create these terminations? How can I enable this.

Comment: Anyway, this still does  not answer the reason why Vscode is not showing up code highlight syntax. I guess that code markup thing is totally related to vscode, it least this is what I imagine

Comment: Thank you very much for sparing some time to help me out =D